# Extract out exact price data as seen in excel sheet using Python without rounding the value on Python's side

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have an excel sheet that contains price data and I want to get this data using Python. The excel sheet looks like this:

```
Unit Price(USD)
---------------
1235.79
1.23
```

The actual value of the price however, is sometimes to 3 decimal places, For example the actual value is 1235.794 and 1.234 respectively.

This is the code I use to extract them. I am using the xlrd module to extract out the data.

```
def bottom_mf(row, col):
    data_list = []
    global stop_iter_row         # constant
    while(row < stop_iter_row):           
        row += 1        
        if isinstance(pd.cell(row, col).value, float):
            data_list.append("%0.15g" % pd.cell(row, col).value)  
        else:
            data_list.append(pd.cell(row, col).value)  
    return data_list
```

A sample of the code that should be functioning if ran:

```
import xlrd as xd
workbook1       = xd.open_workbook("sample.xlsx", on_demand = True)
sheet_names_pdf = workbook1.sheet_names()
pd              = workbook1.sheet_by_name(sheet_names_pdf[0]) 

stop_iter_row = pd.nrows()

def bottom_mf(row, col):
    data_list = []
    global stop_iter_row
    while(row < stop_iter_row):           
        row += 1        
        if isinstance(pd.cell(row, col).value, float):
            data_list.append("%0.15g" % pd.cell(row, col).value)  
        else:
            data_list.append(pd.cell(row, col).value)  
    return data_list

list_of_price = bottom_mf(2, 2)
print(list_of_price)
```

`pd.cell(row, col).value` referring to the price data. The data I am getting is, for example, 1235.794 rather than 1235.79. I know Python can just round up this number to get it, but I want to extract it out exactly as it is seen in the excel sheet. How can I achieve this?

Can xlrd do this or should I use other modules or is rounding up the only way?

Edit 1:

The value extracted using xlrd in the code above is the floating point number from excel, not the data I physically see on the sheet. It's the data I physically see on the sheet that I want to get, Cell 1 may be 1.2345 but the sheet shows 1.23 and Cell 2 could be at 10.456631 but on the sheet it is shown 10.5. The code would need to work with both cells without having to use a rounding method in Python.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202969/discussion-on-question-by-neptuniancustard-extract-out-exact-price-data-as-seen).